# PyNifly Blender .nif Import via script Batch Convert to .fbx

Tags: python, import

I want to batch process nif files, using PyNifly addon, I would like to import a .nif through a script without going through the menu manually.

bpy.ops.import_scene.pynifly() is what I got when enabling developer extras but I get an error when trying to import a file.

Download Blender cube .nif
https://www.dropbox.com/s/5xblr15dkie2xkx/Cube.nif?dl=0

Download PyNifly
https://github.com/BadDogSkyrim/PyNifly

Script

```
    import bpy
    bpy.ops.import_scene.pynifly(filepath="E:/Meshes/10mmAmmo.nif")
```

Console Error

```
Python: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\3.4\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Import of nif failed, see console window for details
```

I installed an addon called ActionRecorder and got this information, about the importing process.

Script

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.pynifly(filepath='', filter_glob='*.nif', files=<bpy_collection[0], IMPORT_SCENE_OT_pynifly.files>, create_bones=True, scale_factor=1.0, rename_bones=True, rename_bones_niftools=False, import_shapes=True, apply_skinning=True)
```

Error

```
Error: invalid syntax (<string>, line 1)
```

System Console Log

```
====================================
PYNIFLY IMPORT NIF V7.0.0


ERROR:pynifly:Import of nif failed
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\3.4\scripts\addons\io_scene_nifly\__init__.py", line 1955, in execute
    NifImporter.do_import(fullfiles, flags)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\3.4\scripts\addons\io_scene_nifly\__init__.py", line 1874, in do_import
    imp = NifImporter(filename, flags, chargen=chargen, scale=scale)
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\3.4\scripts\addons\io_scene_nifly\__init__.py", line 785, in __init__
    self.filename = filename[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
INFO:pynifly:

PyNifly IMPORT of [] completed WITH ERRORS {'CANCELLED'}
====================================


Error: Import of nif failed, see console window for details
ERROR:ActionRecorder:Uncaught exception
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "\Text", line 2, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\Blender Foundation\Blender 3.4\3.4\scripts\modules\bpy\ops.py", line 113, in __call__
    ret = _op_call(self.idname_py(), None, kw)
RuntimeError: Error: Import of nif failed, see console window for details
```

Comment: Did you try seeing the console for details?

Comment: Yes, It's the same as error

Comment: There was no previous log information that gave more detail?

Comment: I added a log, from running the script at the top of my post, I've never seen this before today.

Comment: self.filename = filename[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
This means that the file name is the empty string. Are you trying to select multiple files at once perhaps?

Comment: No the only file in the script is 10mmAmmo.nif

Comment: If you have a look at the pynifly_tests.py file--if it's not shipped it's on the github--you'll see a ton of tests showing how to invoke PyNifly from a Blender script (because that's all the tests are, really). You'll have to figure out how to get the right context but that shouldn't be too hard--you'll have to invoke the main file but convince it not to install itself.

If you just want to hack the files and don't actually need Blender, it's even easier. pynifly.py can be invoked from any python program. At the end of that file are a ton of tests that show you how to use it.

Comment: The answer above is from BadDogSkyrim on GitHub, I still don't have any idea how to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Your script works:

```
bpy.ops.import_scene.pynifly(filepath="E:/dummydir/dummynif.nif")
```

You may want to make sure the file referenced actually exists. It gives the same error message if you reference a file that doesn't exist.